# How to concatenate rows in python pd?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

How can I concatenate two columns of a df into only one?

I've tried lots of possible combinations (with append, with np, with concat )  ... and there's always an error or the table outputs this way

`

```
   A    B

0  75   Nan

1  71   NaN

2  NaN    83

3  NaN    64
```

`

instead of in only 1 column

what do I have to do?

Comment: Do you need to retain column info?  yes -> `melt`, no -> `combine_first`.

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html

Comment: I'm not combining ... or melt ... I need one column after the other one (by rows)

Comment: `df['another_column'] = df.A.combine_first(df.B)` not like this?  if this is not what you want, could you add your expected result?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what data your columns contain and how you want to combine it.

The easiest way is to do:

```
df['new_column'] = df['column1'] + df['column2']
```

To solve the NaN issue you'll need to remove/replace them first. For example, if you are adding columns together, you can replace the NaN's with 0 so that they don't affect the sum.

```
df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: dont like this ... do you have other possibilities

Comment: Can you provide the original dataframe and more context as to what you're trying to get as the output?

Comment: I ended up passing to numpy ... etc.